# JavaFX -> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, javafx

Разрабатываю приложение, по нажатию кнопки открываю модальное окно, выполняю определенные действия. При закрытии данного модального окна -> приложение закрывается с ошибкой.

IDE -> ItellJ IDEA 14;
JDK 1.8;

использую SceneBuilder для формирования *.fxml.

Подскажите в чём дело, заранее спасибо.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7240b836, pid=6208,
>   tid=0x00001eac
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build
>   1.8.0_102-b14)  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode windows-x86 )  Problematic frame:  C  [glass.dll+0x1b836]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
>   client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   D:\Java\OPCClient\hs_err_pid6208.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.

Comment: jvm упала. надо смотреть логи, которые лежат тут D:\Java\OPCClient\hs_err_pid6208.log.

Comment: Похоже, что это особенности HotSpot'a. Если погуглите "jvm hotspot javafx crash", увидите, что вы не одиноки.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду гуглить